# How do I share my Pushmo levels?

Tags: pushmo

I love the game Pushmo. I like the idea of being able to create and share my own levels, but I am not quite sure how to do that. You get a QR code for every level you create - so do I have to physically show my 3DS to someone to share the level? Or is there a website or something somewhere where I cam upload my QR codes (and possibly get QR codes from other players)?

Comment: FYI there is a Pushmo section over at reddit: http://reddit.com/r/pushmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the QR codes to image files on your 3DS, and then visit any image upload site using the 3DS browser in order to share them.  I found [this thread](http://boards.ign.com/nintendo_3ds_lobby/b25212/207362747/p1/?10) over on the IGN boards where people are trading Pushmo QR codes.  I believe loading the game and going into the QR code reader, then aiming your 3DS's camera at the screen should allow you to read them directly off your computer's display.

I believe it is also possible to physically share them as you say - display the QR code on your 3DS, and then use another 3DS's camera to snap a shot of it.